# Is that possible to hide scrollbar(without removing scrolling) phonegap ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, scrollbar

Hi iam working one cordova ios project in that i have one gallery page. Currently images are scrolling vertically and i can see that scroll bar (as shown in image) .But i need to hide that scroll bar on right side, is that possible?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See iScroll: http://iscrolljs.com. It takes over the native scrolling and offers a lot of customizations for the scroll bar itself.

Comment: i need scrolling but how do i remove that scrollbar,

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to this problem by a just adding a couple lines of code to the existing Cordova files. 
Open the `CDVViewController.m` file in 
`CordovaLib.xcodeproj -> Classes -> Cleaver` folder. In the `viewDidLoad` method after `self.webView.scalesPageToFit = [enableViewportScale boolValue];`, paste these two lines to disable both horizontal and vertical scrollbars

```
self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Comment: In latest version of Cordova you should paste your code to `CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewEngine.m`