# Hide Scrollbar in Cordova IOS App

Tags: ios, cordova

This is not work on my ios cordova app, I have tried many ways, but the scrollbar still appear.

`::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none }`

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693573/is-that-possible-to-hide-scrollbarwithout-removing-scrolling-phonegap-ios?rq=1) tell me to add 2 lines to CDVUIWebViewEngine.m file but I dont know where to paste these lines.

`self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;`

I need a solution to hide scollbar entire my Cordova Ios App, please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`, which is transfer your APP from using `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`. After build your APP.

1. find file `platforms/ios/your_APP_name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m`;
2. find lines

```
wkWebView.configuration.preferences.minimumFontSize = [settings cordovaFloatSettingForKey:@"MinimumFontSize" defaultValue:0.0];
wkWebView.allowsLinkPreview = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"AllowLinkPreview" defaultValue:NO];
wkWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"ScrollEnabled" defaultValue:NO];
wkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" defaultValue:NO];
```

3. insert the two lines under them.

```
wkWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
wkWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

It works on iOS 13.